# Conditional Operator (?:) without return value

Tags: c#, linq

First off, I'm just starting to mess around with LINQ, and I don't really understand it.

Anyways, what I'm trying to do is add to a List with LINQ and the .Where statement.

This is what I've tried:

```
List<object> FirstList = new List<object>();
List<object> SecondList = new List<object>();
Listener.Clients.Where(x => (x.Value.Authenticated) ? FirstList.Add(x.Value.UserID) : SecondList.Add(x.Value.UserID));
```

Listener is a socket wrapper class, and Clients is an array of a class, Client.

In that Client class there are a few values that I need, and I want to check if that client is authenticated (logged in), and if it is, add it to the first list, and if it's not, add it to the second list, however it seems that the ?: operator must have a return value, but adding to a list does not return anything.

I hope I explained that good; I'm not the best with words.

Comment: Just use an `if` clause instead.

Comment: `condition ? aye : nay` is an _expression_, so it must have a value.

Comment: What's wrong with `FirstList = (from x in Listener.Clients where x.Value.Authenticated select x.Value.UserID)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to create two (or more) lists with one enumeration.  Consider using `ToLookup` instead:

```
ILookup<bool, Client> lookup = source.ToLookup(c => c.Value.Authenticated);
List<Client> firstList = lookup[true].ToList();
List<Client> secondList = lookup[false].ToList();
```

When an unknown key is sent to the lookup, it will return an empty collection.

---

You want UserIds instead of Clients, so use the overload of ToLookup that selects values.

```
ILookup<bool, string> lookup = source
  .ToLookup(c => c.Value.Authenticated, c => c.Value.UserId);
List<string> firstList = lookup[true].ToList();
List<string> secondList = lookup[false].ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

`IEnumerable.Where` is meant simply to filter elements of a List that match a specific criteria. You're trying to operate inside the Where clause, which is incorrect.

I'm guessing you want something like:

```
var firstList = 
    Listener
        .Clients
        .Where(c => c.Value.Authenticated).Select(c => c.Value.UserID).ToList();
var secondList = 
    Listener
        .Clients
        .Where(c => !c.Value.Authenticated).Select(c => c.Value.UserID).ToList();
```

Comment: This iterates over `Clients` twice. I'd simply use a single `foreach` loop. LINQ doesn't really add much here.

Comment: @hvd - I never said it was a good design decision to use LINQ in this case. I was merely illustrating the proper use of Where to filter.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I decided I'm just going to do a foreach loop.

Comment: Unless you're doing this separation of Clients millions of times a second, who care if you iterate twice.  Code mantainability is more important here (IMO).  Although I would change `var secondList = Listener.Clients.Where(x => !firstList.Contains(x)).ToList();` to be more specific on what it's actually doing.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Making that change would turn the query from O(n) to O(n^2).  Iterating a list twice doesn't actually hurt performance much (unless the underlying sequence is an IQueryable hitting the database, rather than an in-memory list).  But adding that `Contains` in actually hurts the performance rather dramatically.

Comment: @ErikPhilips My comment wasn't solely based on performance. The English description of the question directly translates to a single `foreach` loop containing `if` statements.

Comment: I'd just wrap these 2 lines up in (extension) methods. `GetAuthenticatedUserIds` & `GetUnauthenticatedUserIds` so they can be unit tested.

Answer (score 0):

This IEnumerable.Where exension method is meant to retrieve a filtered list of elements and takes as a parameter an anonymus method that must recieve a Type of your elements and return a bool.